# What is this type of vocals called?

Tags: voice, terminology

I'm wondering what is this type of vocals, what is the humming with the voices instead of singing words called ?

Answer (score 3):

It is called [**Scat singing**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scat_singing).

Per Wikipedia:

> In vocal jazz, scat singing is vocal improvisation with wordless vocables, nonsense syllables or without words at all.

It is pretty common in Jazz. Singers used it to 'solo' (cause they had no instrument).The song you provided is jazzy so I think scat singing is the correct term here.

Here are a few examples:

- ["That Haunting Melody"
  excerpt](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Jolsonscat.ogg)
- ["Heebie Jeebies" excerpt](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Armstrongscat.ogg)

  and

This falls under the 'wordless vocals' category:

Not exactly scatting, but they are both wordless vocals.

Comment: Check out George Benson, who often scats while soloing on guitar.

Comment: The pioneering singer who will always be most strongly associated with scat singing is the great jazz vocalist Ella Fitzgerald.